# Magento table rate cached or not

Tags: magento-1.9, table-rates

I updated magento table rates using CSV,

but in checkout it applies old rates.

because the site is live i cannot flush the cache.

Anyone know magento cached those rates or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First connect sql & check if the `shipping_tablerate` table is having same data as you expect.
2. If **yes** then try `refreshing cache` instead flushing.

If still  no result, then some custom module conflict should be the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, in my case, i found the shipping cost was overridden by a shopping cart rule :)

Comment: Good suggestion. It's always advisable to clear cache.